# Set up C# http module on windows 2003 server in 32-bit mode

Tags: asp-classic, httpmodule

i've got a site set up in Classic Asp on Windows Server 2003 and i'd like to run some HTTP module written in C# on the site when it gets hit.

Is this as simple as putting the module in a subdirectory and sticking a web.config in root? Will that disrupt the Classic ASP stuff?

Answer (score 0):

this might be too convoluted and there may be a much easier way, but I think you can't run ASP and .NET in the same application, so you could put the c# in a folder, create a virtual directory pointing to it and use ajax to call it from your ASP (client side). Or just create another site for it. Just a thought.